# API Key Authentication in Elasticsearch with python

Tags: python, api, authentication, elasticsearch, key

I was hoping to find an answer to my problem with the elasticsearch python framework. Maybe I'm completely blind or doing something absolutely wrong, but I'm very confused right now and can't find an adequate answer.

I'm currently trying to establish a connection to my elastic search API using the [elasticsearch python framework](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/), my code looks like this:

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

def create_es_connection(host: str, port: int, api_key_id: str, api_key: str, user: str, pw: str) -> Elasticsearch:
    return Elasticsearch([f"https://{user}:{pw}@{host}:{port}"])
```

This is working fine. I then created an API key for my *testuser*, which I'm giving to the function above as well. I am now trying to do something similar like this: `Elasticsearch([f"https://{api_key_id}:{api_key}@{host}:{port}"])` so, I want to leave out the user and password completely, because in regards to the greater project behind this snippet, I'm not feeling very well in saving the user/password credentials in my project (and maybe even pushing it to our git server). Sooner or later, these credentials have to be entered somewhere and I was thinking that only saving the API key and to authenticate with that could be more safe. Unfortunately, this isn't working out like I planned and I couldn't find anything about how to authenticate with the API key only.

What am I doing wrong? In fact, I found so little about this, that I'm questioning my  fundamental understanding here. Thank you for your replies!

Answer (score 9):

working configuration for me was :

```
es = Elasticsearch(['localhost:9200'], api_key=('DuSkVm8BZ5TMcIF99zOC','2rs8yN26QSC_uPr31R1KJg'))
```

Comment: This worked for me. `api_key` is apparently using `api_key=('api_key_id', 'api_key')`. This really should be documented somewhere.

Comment: @CptSnuggles I found this [link] (https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/#apikey-authentication) in the documentation. Not sure when it was added, but it seems to be there now!

Comment: this does not work rather i got whole range of http.client.RemoteDisconnected junk

Answer (score 5):

Elasticsearch's documentation shows how to generate and use (at the bottom of the page) an API key: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-create-api-key.html

```
curl -H "Authorization: ApiKey ..." http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health
```

`-H` means "header", so to do the same in Python you will need to set this header. Rummaging through the elasticsearch module source code tells me that you might just be able to do the following:

```py
Elasticsearch([f'http://{host}:{port}'], api_key=api_key)
```

The reason for this is that `**kwargs` of the `Elasticsearch.__init__` method are passed to `Transport.__init__`, the `**kwargs` of that are passed to [`Connection.__init__`, which takes an `api_key` arg](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/d2a0cc62eb56a28ede0ddcb19d6ad4726b437997/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py#L100) which is then used in 
 [`_get_api_key_header_val`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/d2a0cc62eb56a28ede0ddcb19d6ad4726b437997/elasticsearch/connection/base.py#L188) to construct the appropriate header.

The following code shows that the api key header gets added to the HTTP headers of the request:

```py
import elasticsearch, logging, http.client
http.client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 5
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
c = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch(['localhost'], api_key='TestApiKey')
print(c.cluster.health(wait_for_status='green'))
```

This is definitely something that should be added to Elasticsearch's docs.

Comment: Hey Andreas, thank you for your response! Unfortunately, just adding this like you suggested didn't work. Error: [https://pastebin.com/raw/0x96LSJV](https://pastebin.com/raw/0x96LSJV) Further information, I'm currently using all components in the newest version available (Elastic in 7.5.0 and the python framework updated as well).

Comment: I updated my answer to show that passing the `api_key` parameter does set the correct HTTP header. There may be another reason your ES rejects the request - xpack security may be disabled, or you may have to enable HTTPS.

Comment: You were absolutely right, the key is passed down to the header correctly. I could reconstruct it now as well inside the [http_urllib3](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/master/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py). X-Pack and https are actually enabled, but maybe I've misconfigured something down the line somewhere there, gonna double check that.

Comment: So far, I've found some WARN messages in the elasticsearch logs: ```elasticsearch_1  | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-12-19T14:41:57,747Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.x.s.a.AuthenticationService", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch", "message": "Authentication using apikey failed - invalid ApiKey value", "cluster.uuid": "0DNPuMBRQ7yN9SB34yYz9w", "node.id": "vj82JxvhTi6HbfZ5if54Ow" ,
```